# Zoom / magnify tool at the cursor's position

Tags: windows, mouse, accessibility, zoom, magnifier

I'd like to do a screen recording video to demonstrate a product (with OBS recording tool), and be able to zoom at specific parts of the screen to highlight a feature, see [this example](https://blackmagic.so/assets/demo.mp4) for a **beautiful, smooth, zooming-in**.

On MacOS, people do it simply with "Accessibility zoom" feature, and the zoom is triggered when <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + mouse scroll is done (see screenshot below).

**How to do the same on Windows, ie. zoom on specific parts of the screen with <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + mouse scroll?**

Note: it's important that the zooming is smooth, and that no tool UI like this is displayed on the screen when doing this:

[image]

Can this be done with Windows 7, with built-in tools? If not possible on Windows 10?

---

As a comparison, here is the MacOS tool:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just minimise the toolbar, the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>[image: winlogo]</kbd><kbd>**+**</kbd> for zooming in, <kbd>[image: winlogo]</kbd><kbd>**-**</kbd> for zooming out and <kbd>[image: winlogo]</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> for resetting to 100%) won't stop working then. Default setting (can be changed) is to zoom in on the current cursor location.

[image]

You can then either present in full screen, or autohide the taskbar. Both of these will additionally make the (minimised) task bar item go away.

Zoom increments can be changed in the 'ease of access magnifier settings':

[image]

Comment: Oh, I thought you were familiar with it! WIN and the PLUS (or MINUS) key. Default settings are it zooms in around the cursor. WIN ESC resets zoom to 100%.

Comment: Fairly smooth. It doesn't do an instant jump from x1 to x4 if that's what you mean.

Comment: I've elaborated the answer a bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to zoom x1 to x2 instead of x4? PS: sideremark out of topic here: WIN+minus doesn't work on french keyboard, as usual the minus isn't well understood on french keyboards ;)

Comment: Also, on Windows 7, the zoomed view is very pixelated, like a zoom on a bitmap. Is it the same on Win 10? It's not the same on MacOS: https://blackmagic.so/assets/demo.mp4

Comment: You can 'change zoom increments' in the accessibility settings for magnifier. 5% zoom steps is the minimum, 400% is the max.

Comment: Thanks again for your update @MiG, great answer! PS: (out of topic here but slightly related) do you know if there exists another tool (freeware) with more customization? Smoothness of zoom / zoom speed, customize keyboard screenshots, etc.

Comment: You're welcome! And I'm afraid not, I just went to using bigger screens :)